# Use maven offline

Tags: java, maven

Our company policies prevent programmer to connect their pc to internet. And we need to use maven in order manage our builds. So we made an internet-pc that contain a local maven repository, and created another local maven repository on the server. the problem is how to synchronize the two repositories in a way to find the new artifact installed in the internet repo and copy them to the server repo.
One way is to made a tool that copy the structure of the .m2 with the new created files using created date, but is there a better solution.

**Edit:**
The internet-pc is not connected to the local network.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018965/maven-workspace-local-repository

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus), with proxy repositories enabled (defaults for the main open-source repositories are preinstalled).

(And look for other job options; this sounds like a horribly-run company!)

Comment: The various alternatives for Nexus (Archivia etc.) were discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165846/best-enterprise-repository-tool-for-maven-2

Comment: 10x, nexus provide a way to copy my artifact from the internet-pc repo to server repo? (just want to insure before start reading full nexus docs)

Comment: @primeFaceUser It would be a real pain. If the management of your company absolutely refuses to let programmers on the Internet (which is asinine; no docs, no SO, etc.), then at least put the Nexus server in a DMZ where it can access the Internet and the programmers can access it, even if they can't get all the way to the Internet (or multihome it).